# Include a customized calculated field in MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to execute a calculated field in MS Access. 
Background

I have a single table including fields such as:

```
Name Week Hours_Charged
X    21-06  10
Y    21-06  20
X    21-06  30
Z    21-06  40
```

I am trying to create a new field in the query wherein it says Gap and contains the substraction from 40.

Additionally, it will should group according to the Same names. So the expected output would be:

```
Name Week Hours_Charged Gap
    X    21-06  40      0
    Y    21-06  20      -20   
    Z    21-06  40      0
```

Conditions: With the same name, there can be various dates and hours. However, the idea remains same.

Any leads on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried implementing through the design mode but was not successful.

Comment: I suggest you to use a different name for field `Name` because it's a reserved word for system, and it may cause problems. Something like `_Name_` or `MyName` or whatever, but not `Name`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, I've changed the Name to a different nomenclature. Thank you for your help

Comment: There Should be a Employee-Table with given name, last name, adress, etc and `DefaultHours`Field in the for each employee, as Weekly-Hours can change and depend on standing and contract, referenced by a foreign key in the Hours-Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replied your table like this:

[image]

And got this query:

[image]

SQL code of this query (please note I've used different field names):

```
SELECT Table1.MyName, Table1.MyWeek, Sum(Table1.Hours_Charged) AS SumaDeHours_Charged, 40-[SumaDeHours_Charged] AS GAP
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.MyName, Table1.MyWeek;
```

And design view of this query in MS Access (Please, note my Access is in spanish, so name of rows in design view are in spanish, not in english. If you want to know the meaning of something, you can ask me or use the SQL code:

[image]

Comment: Additionally, I have a form in background which fills this data. I want to add a leave management kind of stuff. Like if someone takes 3 hours off, then a field shows leaves (in hours) and gap is calculated automatically. Is it possible to do so? I'll be including a separate field in my backend table as well as forms.

Comment: That is a totally different question. You should open a new one, and post what you've done, a true data example, and where are you stuck.